# Loading immediately methods on pages (live) inside index

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using `niceScroll.js` for small nice scroll bar in my pages for mobile.
the call is simply :

```
$("#myPage").niceScroll();
```

Because I working with Jquery Mobile so for each page that should have scroll I start it this way:

```
$('#pageID').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
            $("#test1").niceScroll();
          });
```

But the problem is that for creating popUps I am using some methods that get ID and display it as a popUp, so I writing this page **inside** the index.html page.

```
<div id="popUpPage"> 
 // come code...
 </div>
```

The problem is that I dont have how to detect the loading of the page so 1 sec after the `onClick` I start an timer...and the start it.

```
  setTimeout(function () { $("#popUpPage #trt").niceScroll(); },1000);
```

The problem is sometimes I need 1 sec and sometimes 2 in other devices...when It starting its changes immediately the page. How can I lunch this page and immediately after the popUp appears start my function and save the syntax of page inside the `index.html`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this on `pageinit`? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/

Comment: I tried it: `$("#popUpPage").live('pageinit', function () {
                  alert("test");
              });` but it's not works,maybe because the page #popUpPage is inside index.html

Comment: How do you call the popup?

Comment: I'm creating a new DIV with some CSS settings,and display it over the page with
        `position: 'absolute'
        overflow: 'hidden'
        display: 'none' `